# Unable to install pip on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04

On my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, when I try to install boto3 I get

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

I then try to install pip using `sudo apt install python-pip` and I get

```sh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
```

I then try and install pip using the directions [here](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/) but when I run

```sh
python get-pip.py
```

I get

```sh
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Is the website I linked an appropriate way of installing pip, and if so how do I resolve my permissions error? I'm using python 2.7.9.

Comment: install it as root for all users - `sudo python get-pip.py` - or use `--user` to instal only only for you - `python get-pip.py --user`

Comment: thanks, when I now run `pip install boto3` I get ```python File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main```

Comment: Consider using the `--user` option. Consider also the warning given in the linked site: "Be cautious if you are using a Python install that is managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.".

Comment: it is Ubuntu from 2014.04 so it is 5 years old and it has very old `pip` - current has version `19.1.1` - `pip -V` (upper `V`). Better use `get-pip.py` to install newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Install conda (the best: miniconda - since more lightweight than Anaconda).
This you do by going to this site: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Take care, which OS and whether 32bit or 64bit.
E.g. Linux 32 bit

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh
```

Or Linux 64 bit

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

And for installation you do:

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh
```

or

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

, respectively, in the terminal.
After that, any command starting with `conda` in terminal will work.

conda solves such dependency problems you have now.

create an environment useful for this stuff

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv         # enter then newly created environment
```

Then, installing pip is super easy:

```
# the new environment e.g. here, <myenv>
conda install pip # this installs automatically newest Python and pip
# you could also do: 
conda install git pip 
# if you also want to pip install directly from github repositories
```